# Pass null as default value with DropdownFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I've quite problem with one dropdown as I need him to be not mandatory. I found some solutions with nullable type like int?, but that is only for the int, datetime and etc. but my type in model is other object(reference). To put it simple I have team structure and some of the teams do not have parents so that reference should be null, so how can I do that the dropdown list don't have to be selected and I get the null value for parent team

Model (Simplified):

```
    public class Team
    {
         public Team ParentTeam { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
     var listTeam = (from team in listOfTeams.AsEnumerable()
                        select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = team.Name,
                            Value = team.ID.ToString()
                        }).ToList();

        SelectList dropDownlistOfTeams = new SelectList(listTeam, "Value", "Text");
```

And View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentTeam, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentTeam, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListOfTeams, "-- Set Parent --")
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `ParentTeam` is a complex object (typeof `Team`). You cannot bind a `<select">` element to a complex object! And why are you using `new SelectList()` to create an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from your existing `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`?

Comment: Yes you are right there should be `model.ParentTeam.ID` instead of `model.ParentTeam`. To be honest I found the SelectList() code in some tutorial so I thought it was best practice (learning C# MVC on my own so I guess I have a lot of dirty code in there).

Comment: Note you do not and should not be adding a select list item with a `null` values as per the answer you accepted. Your `DropDownList()` method is already adding the default label option with the `null` value (although it should probably be `"-- Please select parent --"` or something a bit more descriptive. If that option is selected, then `null` will be posted to the controller

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well I tried that before, but it still force the dropdown for some value - it was not possible to submit the form.

Comment: I assume you misunderstanding some concepts. You can only bind a select element to a value type, not a complex object so `model.ParentTeam.ID` will work but `model.ParentTeam` will not. If the `ID` property of `ParentTeam` is `int` then posting back a `null` will case a validation error because and `int` cannot be null. Adding a second option with `value=""` as per the accepted answer does nothing to solve your problem.

Comment: I don't say that them perfectly, so can you suggest some solution for this?

Comment: As always, you should be using a view model which will contain a property (say) `int? ParentTeamID`. The change the view to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentTeamID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListOfTeams, "-- None --")` If the user selects the `"--None--"` option then when you post back the value of `ParentTeamID` will be null, otherwise it will be the selected ID of the `ParentTeam`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, so viewmodel, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Controller, simply add a null team.

```
listTeam.Add(new SelectListItem() {Text="None", Value=null});
```